# Advice on correct usage of conditional expectation (proof verification)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

Assume $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent and identically distributed random variables where $X \in \{-1, 1\}$ with equal probabilities, and $S_k$ represents their cumulative sum of up to $k$ variables.

> The exercise is to show that $\mathbb{E}S_{\tau}^2 = \mathbb{E}\tau$, where $\tau$ is a $(\mathcal{F})_n$ measurable stopping time.

On one hand, it feels like

$$ \mathbb{E}\tau = \sum_{j=1}^nj \mathbb{P}(\tau=j)=\sum_{j=1}^n j \mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{\tau = j})$$

On the other hand,

$$ \mathbb{E}(S^2_\tau)=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}(S_j^2 \mathbb{1}_{\tau = j})=\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}( \mathbb{E}[S_j^2 \mathbb{1}_{\tau = j}|\mathcal{F}_j]) = \sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{1}_{\tau = j} \mathbb{E}[S_j^2 |\mathcal{F}_j])$$

In essence, it is easy to check that $\mathbb{E}(S_j^2)=j$ due to equal probabilities.

**My question**: is the last equation a proper way to pull out the $j$ from the expectation? That is, by stating that $\mathbb{E}(S_j^2 | \mathcal{F}_j)=j$? It feels like double expectation here is one way to pull out the $j$, but not entirely sure whether $\mathcal{F}_j$ is the right choice here, since it makes the $S_j^2$ measurable.

On the other hand, is pulling out the $j$ necessary, or is it for some reason obvious that
$$ \mathbb{E}S_j^2 \mathbb{1}_{\tau=j} = j \mathbb{P}(\tau = j)?$$

Comment: @d.k.o If I'm not mistaken, $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2) = 1$ due to squares, and $\mathbb{E}(X_i X_j) = 1\cdot 1 \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2 + (-1)\cdot 1 \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2  +  1\cdot (-1) \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2  + (-1)\cdot (-1) \cdot (\frac{1}{2})^2  = 0$ for $i \neq j$, so $\mathbb{E}(S_j^2)$ should reduce to $\sum \mathbb{E}X_i^2 = j$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, $\{S_k^2-k\}$ is a martingale. Since $\tau\le n$, the [optional stopping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem) implies
$$
\mathsf{E}[S_{\tau}^2-\tau]=\mathsf{E}[S_1^2-1]=0.
$$

---

Regarding your question, let $n=4$, $\tau:=\min\left(\{k\ge 1:S_k\ge 1 \}\cup\{n\}\right)$. Then
$$
3\times\mathsf{P}(\tau=3)=\frac{3}{8},
$$
but
$$
\mathsf{E}[S_\tau^21\{\tau=3\}]=\mathsf{E}[S_\tau^2\mid \tau=3]\mathsf{P}(\tau=3)=\frac{1}{8}.
$$

Direct computation shows that
$$
\mathsf{E}\tau=\sum_{j=1}^4 j\mathsf{P}(\tau=j)= 1\times\frac{1}{2}+2\times 0+3\times\frac{1}{8}+4\times\frac{3}{8}=\frac{19}{8}
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{E}S_\tau^2=\sum_{j=1}^4 \mathsf{E}[S_\tau^21\{\tau=j\}]=\frac{1}{2}+0+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{7}{4}=\frac{19}{8}.
$$

Comment: great counterexample, thanks. I still need to wrap my head around conditional expectations, apparently.